# Posting to an unauthenticated user's wall using the facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

is it possible to post to the wall (using the graph api) when the user is not authenticated into Facebook? I tried replacing the me in `FB.api('/me/feed/', 'post'...` with the user id, but it didn't work.  Quora is able to post a message on my fb wall even when I am logged out of FB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you need the user to grant you the offline_access permission.

This is from Facebook documentation:
Enables your application to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user at any time. By default, most access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application. This permission makes the access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived.

Comment: Just a side note: Most users will not grant you this permission happily, from experience. Consider if you really need this, and know that it will reduce the number of users that authorize your application.

Comment: Good point.  So basically if they are logged out of facebook, I should display the Connect to Facebook link EVEN though they had already connected to FB earlier and I have their id, right?

Comment: That's right. Users are getting used to it. It's just the way things work. No reason to look for a workaround, IMHO.

Comment: Cool, that's probably what I'd do then.  BTW, for offline access, I'll have to use the id instead of me right?

Comment: Yes. That's what I did anyway.